# Cosine similarity for Categorical datasets?

Tags: correlation, euclidean, cosine-similarity, cosine-distance

Can I use Cosine similarity measure for estimating similarity/relationship between D1 and D2 (two categorical datasets)

[image]

Comment: Are you going to treat your levels as ordinal or nominal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use cosine similarity between D1 and D2 after encoding them as they are ordinal variables i.e preserves the order among the feature values.